# Find a way to move 3 pieces to the target position by taking symmetry

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, chess

On the Ox coordinate axis, there are initially 3 pieces at x, y, z. At each step you can move a piece according to the rule: If there are 2 pieces in position n and m then move the piece in position n to position n' symmetrical to n through m if n' has no pieces. Find a way to move 3 pieces at x, y, z so that at the end we get 3 pieces at u, v, w.

- **Input**: 6 numbers x, y, z and u, v, w. (-10^6 < x,y,z,u,v,w < 10^6)
- **Output**: K - number of steps moved. The next K lines are the positions of the 3 pieces in each step

---

Example:

- Input:

```
3 4 5 1 2 3
```

Currently 3 chess pieces are at positions 3,4,5, need to move them to positions 1,2,3

- Output:

```
2
3 2 5
3 2 1
```

[The move of the above example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs0M0.png)

- Step 0: 3 4 5
- Step 1: Positions 4 and 3 both have pieces, **move the piece at position 4 to 2** (because 2 is the symmetry of 4 over 3 and there are no pieces at 2) => 3, **2**, 5
- Step 2: Positions 5 and 3 both have pieces, **move the piece in position 5 to 1** (because 1 is the symmetry of 5 over 3 and there are no pieces at 1) => 3, 2, **1**

---

Note:

- As long as 3 pieces are obtained in u,v,w, it is not necessary to return chess piece 1 to u, piece 2 to v, and piece 3 to return to w.
- You can move as many times as you want

---

My idea is to use backtracking to look at all cases. But (-10^6 <= u, v, w, a, b, c <= 10^6) so my algorithm got TLE.

Is there a better approach? Thanks everyone.